# PostgreSQL: Sum of values related via LATERAL join

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

I'm trying to clean up data in a PostgreSQL table, where some records have a large number of profanities in the `email_address` column (the records in question have been entered by agitated users as a result of frustration due to a bug that has since been fixed):

```
    ┌───────────────────┐
    │   email_address   │
    ├───────────────────┤
    │ foo@go.bar.me.net │
    │ foo@foo.com       │
    │ foo@example.com   │
    │ baz@example.com   │
    │ barred@qux.com    │
    └───────────────────┘
```

## Desired query output

I'd like to build a query that annotates each row from the data table with a profanity score, and orders the records by the score, so that a human can go through the annotated data (presented in a web app) and take necessary action:

```
    ┌───────────────────┬───────┐
    │ email_address     │ score │
    ├───────────────────┼───────┤
    │ foo@foo.com       │    18 │
    │ foo@go.bar.me.net │    14 │
    │ foo@example.com   │     9 │
    │ baz@example.com   │     3 │
    │ barred@qux.com    │     0 │
    └───────────────────┴───────┘
```

---

## Attempt #1

The approach I'm taking is to build a list of regular expressions (now I have 2 problems...) and scores, whereby very profane words will contribute a large profanity score if that word is found in the email_address column.  My `profanities` table looks something like this:

```
    ┌──────────────────┬───────┐
    │ profanity_regexp │ score │
    ├──────────────────┼───────┤
    │ foo              │     9 │
    │ bar(?!red)       │     5 │
    │ baz              │     3 │
    └──────────────────┴───────┘
```

### LATERAL JOIN

I've found that I can use a `LATERAL` join over the `regexp_matches` function to extract all profanities from each `email_address` (but records with no profanities are discarded):

```
SELECT
    data.email_address,
    array_agg(matches)
FROM
    data,
    profanities p,
    LATERAL regexp_matches(data.email_address, p.posix_regexp, 'gi') matches
GROUP BY
    data.email_address;
```

This produces the following result:

```
    ┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
    │   email_address   │ profanities_found │
    ├───────────────────┼───────────────────┤
    │ foo@foo.com       │ {{foo},{foo}}     │
    │ foo@example.com   │ {{foo}}           │
    │ foo@go.bar.me.net │ {{foo},{bar}}     │
    │ baz@example.com   │ {{baz}}           │
    └───────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

### SUB-SELECT

I also figured out how to get an array of profanity score subtotals for each record with this SQL:

```
SELECT
    data.email_address,
    array(
        SELECT score * ( 
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM (SELECT
                regexp_matches(data.email_address, p.posix_regexp, 'gi')
            ) matches
        )
        FROM profanities p
    ) prof
from data;
```

Which correctly yields all rows (including rows without profanities) as such:

```
    ┌───────────────────┬──────────┐
    │   email_address   │   prof   │
    ├───────────────────┼──────────┤
    │ foo@go.bar.me.net │ {9,5,0}  │
    │ foo@foo.com       │ {18,0,0} │
    │ foo@example.com   │ {9,0,0}  │
    │ baz@example.com   │ {0,0,3}  │
    │ barred@qux.com    │ {0,0,0}  │
    └───────────────────┴──────────┘
```

---

## Problem

*How do I sum the result of a lateral join to get the desired output?*

*Is there another strategy I can use to get the desired result?*

---

I've posted a live code fiddle for this question at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6685c/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had previously accepted the answer by @daurnimator, but then found the extra `LATERAL` join isn't necessary.  Here's what I ended up using in my app:

```
SELECT
    data.email_address,
    (
        SELECT
            coalesce(sum(s.score), 0) AS score
        FROM
            profanities,
            LATERAL (
                SELECT
                    profanities.score * array_length(
                        regexp_matches(
                            data.email_address,
                            profanities.profanity_regexp,
                            'gi'
                        ),
                        1
                    ) score
            ) s
    ) AS score
FROM
    data;
```

It also turns out my version is [slightly faster](https://explain.depesz.com/s/oFIR) since it avoids a [nested loop](https://explain.depesz.com/s/qJNi) in the query.  Another advantage is that it can be used as an annotation with Django's `RawSQL` function in my application, allowing me to then `order_by('-score')` and show the most profane entries first.

Comment: Usually you'd want to use the score as an additional filter; e.g. only return email addresses where the score is at least 50. With my approach you're able to use that in the `where` clause. Of course you could move your query to a subselect.....

Answer (score 1):

Add another select to your query. The current query is fine but you just need to sum the array.

```
SELECT email_address,
(
    SELECT SUM(s)
    FROM
        UNNEST(prof.profanity_score_subtotals) s
) AS sum_prof FROM (
    SELECT
        data.email_address,
        array(
            SELECT score * ( 
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM (SELECT
                    regexp_matches(data.email_address, p.profanity_regexp, 'gi')
                ) matches
            )
            FROM profanities p
        ) profanity_score_subtotals
    FROM data
) prof;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work, though I understand using `UNNEST` is the key to your answer, combined with the sub-select query I posted in the question.  My interpretation of your answer is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6685c/17 -- want to expand your answer?

Comment: I took a look at the fiddle. Maybe I misunderstood your requirements but it seems to be working fine. The final query outputs exactly the desired output.

Comment: Weird - I looked again and indeed it works. I've no idea why it wasn't working earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason postgres doesn't allow you to use set-returning functions as part of a where clause, so you need to do two lateral joins:

```
SELECT
    data.email_address,
    t.score
FROM
    data,
    LATERAL (
        SELECT
            coalesce(sum(s.score), 0) AS score
        FROM
            profanities,
            LATERAL (
                SELECT
                    profanities.score * array_length(
                        regexp_matches(
                            data.email_address,
                            profanities.profanity_regexp,
                            'gi'
                        ),
                        1
                    ) score
            ) s
    ) t;
```

Comment: I like this answer better as it worked out of the box, and it uses lateral joins as asked in the title of the question.

Comment: Turns out the extra `LATERAL` join isn't necessary, see my answer for a slightly faster solution.